# python - "if in" statement for multiple possibilities

Tags: python

I want to check if a question mark or a dot are in the last position of a word. So doing something like:

```
if ".","?" in word[-1]:
```

Or:

```
if [".","?"] in word[-1]:
```

Result in an invalid syntax. What is the right way to do this? (preferably without regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the order backwards.

```
if word[-1] in ".?":
```

Refer to the `in` operator in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)

Answer (score 3):

For this *particular* case, where you want to check the end:

```
if word.endswith(('.','?')):
```